# Update column to decrease string limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, mysql2

I am trying to update a field in my database to decrease the character limit of a string. The old migration looked like this:

```
class AddNoSaleLabelToCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :no_sale_label, :string, :limit => 18, :default => "NO SALE"
  end
end
```

I created a new migration that looks like this:

```
class UpdateNoSaleLabelLimit < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :companies, :no_sale_label, :string, :limit => 17, :default => "NO SALE"
  end

  def down
    change_column :companies, :no_sale_label, :string, :limit => 18, :default => "NO SALE"
  end
end
```

When I run the migration it BOMBS and I get an error:

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Data truncated for column 'no_sale_label' at row 1: ALTER TABLE `companies` CHANGE `no_sale_label` `no_sale_label` var
char(17) DEFAULT 'NO SALE'
```

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening, any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this as a comment but i'm not allowed to yet - so what is the data in the no_sale_label column on row 1, specifically, is it 18 characters.  If so, I suggest a quick UPDATE statement so that all existing values are reduced to no more than 17.